# Compiling MIT MEEP In Visual C++ 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, fftw, blas, meep

I know it's possible to do since I have seen some internet articles about it, but none specifically outline the process.

I would like to compile [MIT MEEP](http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/Meep) to Visual C++ to use the libmeep libraries in a .NET CLR application. The source provided includes the associated build scripts for a GNU toolchain, but given that I am using Windows, these are unavailable. As well, it requires some dependencies such as blas, fftw, and optionally libctl and hdf5.

I'm not super experienced on this issue. How would I manually configure Visual Studio to build? What would be the specific process?

Comment: Create a native (not .NET, C++ not C++/CLI) static library project for MEEP and its dependencies.  Use a project reference to drag that static library into your C++/CLI project.  That way all this code will compile normally, without `/clr`, but you can still use it from your `/clr` code.

Comment: Sorry - but the problem is more related to configuring the build without a GNU toolchain (can't use minGW or cygwin here). I take it a static lib compiled with gcc in minGW will not be usable with a Visual C++ project.

Comment: Do you know how to create a VS project for basic "Hello, world" sources? If you tried that, you should have at least some specific errors that you can try to resolve, and failing that ask here. As it stand now, you seem to ask for guidance all the way. That's far too broad for a single question, really, and at the same time the answer would be too specific for just your case.

Comment: Sorry for my vague description. I'm currently tracking down all of the dependencies and building.

Some are missing, such as 'unistd.h' among others. I will try to get the Windows Subsystem for Unix - would this help?

Comment: Unfortunately, even after trying to find equivalents for unistd.h, io.h and process.h in Windows don't seems to fix the UNIX symlink functions not being defined...